# Пройти HTTP Basic Auth через python3

Tags: python-3.x, requests, auth

Не могу попасть на сайт через requests
При входе через браузер вижу [image: окно входа на сайте]

Пробовал так:
`requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))`

И так: `requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))`

В любом случае приходит 401

Работает только через selenium, но для данной задачи он не подходит
Еще через Postman пробовал зайти, в Authorization указывал Basic Auth, тоже 401 ответ приходил. Может это не Basic Auth? Кто сможет помочь?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#basic-authentication

Comment: это бэйсик, проверь правильный ли пароль

Comment: github я для примера указал

Comment: Сайт на который пытаюсь зайти knowledgecenter.assaabloyentrance.net

Comment: Пароль, как и логин верны

Comment: этот сайт просит NTLM

Comment: https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm ставь

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло